# Import a .sql file from MSSQL into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, migration

I have an MSSQL dump file that I want to import into a MySQL database. I attempted doing so via phpMyAdmin and setting the compatibility to MSSQL but that doesn't seem to work. It consistently throws `MySQL server has gone away`.  Upping the `max_allowed_packet` and `wait_timeout` didn't do anything to solve that either.

Is there a better way to import this database dump?

Comment: do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: yes, I have root on the server

Answer (score 0):

Try SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), an ETL tool (Extract, Transform and Load) which is very much needed for the Data warehousing applications. Also SSIS is used to perform operations like loading the data based on the need, performing different transformations on the data.
Free from MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731.aspx
Useful links:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155829/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Part-1-Basics

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you have dealt with all syntax incompatibilities, you can use this:

```
mysql -u<user> -p < db_backup.sql
```

If you are just scripting tables and data that should work fine. If you have `GO` statements in your script remove them, you don't need them for tables and inserts.

If you want to script other objects too you need to review each one as there are significant syntax differences.

Comment: @AkiRoss, while it might not answer your particular question, it did - I believe - answer the OP's question. So I would appreciate for you to undo the down-vote and then ask your question in a new thread.

Comment: Sebastian, my question is exactly the same of OP. I don't like to give down votes and I always motivate why I give them, and I'd be glad to remove it if you can fix your answer. For example, give a reference on how to fix syntax incompatibilities, or a tool for doing so.

Comment: The syntax incompatibilities you mention are exactly the reason why this is a difficult problem to solve.  There are major, major syntax incompatibilities.